# Remove last digit from String depending on length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove the last digit in the df[4] string if the string is over 5 digits.

I tried adding .str[:-1] to df[4]=df[4].astype(str) this removes the last digit from every string in the dataframe.

```
df[3]=df[3].astype(str)
df[4]=df[4].astype(str).str[:-1]
df[5]=df[5].astype(str)
```

I tried several different combinations of if statements but none have worked. 
I'm new to python and pandas so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter first on the string length:

```
condition = df[4].astype(str).str.len() > 5
df.loc[condition, 4]=df.loc[condition, 4].astype(str).str[:-1]
```

For example:

```
>>> df
           4
0          1
1         11
2        111
3       1111
4      11111
5     111111
6    1111111
7   11111111
8  111111111
>>> condition = df[4].astype(str).str.len() > 5
>>> df.loc[condition, 4]=df.loc[condition, 4].astype(str).str[:-1]
>>> df
          4
0         1
1        11
2       111
3      1111
4     11111
5     11111
6    111111
7   1111111
8  11111111
```

If these are natural integers, it is however more efficient to divide by 10:

```
condition = df[4].astype(str).str.len() > 5
df.loc[condition, 4]=df.loc[condition, 4] // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## Accessing Elements of a Collection

```
>>> x = "123456"

# get element at index from start
>>> x[0]
'1'

# get element at index from end
>>> x[-1]
'6'

# get range of elements from n-index to m-index
>>> x[0:3]
'123'
>>> x[1:-2]
'234'
>>> x[-4:-2]
'34'

# get range from/to index with open end/start
>>> x[:-2]
'1234'
>>> x[4:]
'56'
```

## List Comprehension Syntax

I haven't see the [pythons list comprehension syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which really cool and easy.

```
# input data frame with variable string length 1 to n
df = [
    'a',
    'ab',
    'abc',
    'abcd',
    'abcdf',
    'abcdfg',
    'abcdfgh',
    'abcdfghi',
    'abcdfghij',
    'abcdfghijk',
    'abcdfghijkl',
    'abcdfghijklm'
]

# using list comprehension syntax: [element for element in collection]
df_new = [
    # short hand if syntax: value_a if True else value_b
    r if len(r) <= 5 else r[0:5] 
    for r in df 
]
```

Now `df_new` contains only string up to a length of 5:

```
[
 'a',
 'ab',
 'abc',
 'abcd',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf',
 'abcdf'
]
```

Answer (score -1):

cause [-1]removes last numbers or change number to -1 
try `str df[4]=-1`